# Reverse arrow tip but keep line length

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows

I am wondering if there is a way to reverse the arrow tip but keep the length of the line constant? I checked the `arrow.meta` documentation, but could not find something like `rotate` ...

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[orange, very thin] (0.93,-0.5) -- (0.93,1.5);
        \draw[orange, very thin] (1,-0.5) -- (1,1.5);
%       \draw[orange, very thin] (1.07,-0.5) -- (1.07,1.5);

        \draw[-{>[length=0.07cm]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
        \draw[-{<[length=0.07cm]}] (0,0.5) -- (1,0.5);
%       \draw[-{>[rotate=180]}] (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw[-{<[length=0.07cm]}] (0,1) -- (1.07,1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my example, I defined the length of the tip and added the length to the total length, but maybe there is an easier way to do it?

Comment: An alternative is to use `shorten >=` with a negative length: `\draw[-{<[length=0.07cm]}, shorten >=-.07cm] (0,1) -- (1,1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the great comment from Sandy G, I recommend to create a `tikzset` for this, to let you use it even with predfined nodes and not having to do any calculation everytimes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{%
        revarrow/.style={-{<[length=#1]},shorten >=-#1},
        circ/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=black,label={#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path (0,0) node[circ=A](A){} --++ (3,0) node[circ=B](B){};
        \draw[orange,revarrow=.5cm,thick] (A.center)--(B.center);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: shorten reverse arrow]

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. The next time, I can use this approach.